# android layout fixed size

Tags: java, android

I have next xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight=".10">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#aa0000"
            android:text="top"/>    

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight=".70">

        <ScrollView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00aa00">
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView 

                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
                    android:textSize="50pt"
                    android:text="center">
                </TextView>
                <TextView 

                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
                    android:textSize="50pt"
                    android:text="center">
                </TextView>
                <TextView 

                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
                    android:textSize="50pt"
                    android:text="center">
                </TextView>
                <TextView 

                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
                    android:textSize="50pt"
                    android:text="center">
                </TextView>
                <TextView 

                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
                    android:textSize="50pt"
                    android:text="center">
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>    
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight=".20">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#0000aa"
            android:text="bottom"/> 
       </LinearLayout>        


</LinearLayout>
```

In the main LinearLayout i have three LinearLayout. For the first LinearLayout i need set 100px. For the third LinearLayout i need set 200px. And all other size for second LinearLayout.

Comment: You don't seem to have a question. How about simply setting the desired sizes? (If you don't know which tags to use, check the documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a fixed size is not recommended in Android, as it may break your layout in different screen resolution. You should use `android:layout_weight` for defining this type of screen ratio. Lastly, don't use px for defining layout size and pt for text size use dp and sp respectively.